# How can I make variables so that I don't have to repeat myself in future functions

Tags: javascript, variables

WARNING!! I AM A NOVICE THROUGH AND THROUGH

Alright, so I know there have been a lot questions about Global variables, and I think that's what I'm looking for, but, not exactly. Lately I've been needing to call upon the same lines of code several times. `document.getElementById("example").style` or similar to little things like that but I need to continuously repeat.

My question is how do I make it so that I make one variable, outside of the function, to save time writing these lines?

What I've been seeing is to simply write it outside like this `var inferno = document.getElementById("inferno");` but this is far from working.

This is my code right now, it's simple because I was just using it as a test, but can anyone help me?

```
var inferno = document.getElementById("inferno");


function infernoClick () {
    inferno.style.backgroundColor="red";
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code. This is the way you need to do.

Answer (score 3):

You have the right idea. Note, though, that the variable doesn't have to be *global*. It just has to be where all of the code that wants to use it can use it.

For example, this creates a global:

```
<script>
var inferno = document.getElementById("inferno");

function infernoClick () {
    inferno.style.backgroundColor="red";
}

function somethingElse () {
    inferno.style.color="green";
}
</script>
```

(Note that this needs to be *after* the markup creating the `inferno` element.)

The problem with globals is that they can conflict with each other, and in fact the global "namespace" is really, really crowded already.

You can avoid that by wrapping up the code that needs `inferno` in a *scoping function*, like this:

```
<script>
(function() {
    var inferno = document.getElementById("inferno");

    function infernoClick () {
        inferno.style.backgroundColor="red";
    }

    function somethingElse () {
        inferno.style.color="green";
    }
})();
</script>
```

That code creates an anonymous function and then calls it immediately, running the code inside.

Now `inferno` is "global" to the functions that need it, but *isn't* actually a global.

Let's take a further example:

```
<script>
(function() {
    var outer = 42;

    function doSomethingCool() {
        var inner = 67;

        document.getElementById("someElement").onclick = function() {
            alert("inner = " + inner + ", outer = " + outer);
        };
    }

    // Can't use `inner` here, but can use `outer`
    alert("outer = " + outer);

    doSomethingCool();
})();
</script>
```

That code wraps everything in a scoping function, and the `outer` variable is accessible everywhere within that scoping function. It also has a function, `doSomethingCool`, which has a variable called `inner`. `inner` is only accessible within `doSomethingCool`. Look at what `doSomethingCool` does: It hooks up an event handler for when `someElement` is clicked. It doesn't *call* the function, it just hooks it up.

The really cool thing is that *later*, when someone clicks the element, that function has access to that `inner` variable.

And in fact, that's true for arguments you pass into the function as well. One last example:

```
<input type="button" id="element1" value="One">
<input type="button" id="element2" value="Two">
<script>
(function() {
    function hookItUp(id, msg) {
        document.getElementById(id).onclick = function() {
            alert(msg);
        };
    }

    hookItUp("element1", "This message is for element1");
    hookItUp("element2", "And this one is for element2");

})();
</script>
```

There, we have this function that accepts a couple of arguments, and we call it twice: Once to hook up `click` on `element1`, and again to hook up `click` on `element2`.

The really cool thing here is that even though the clicks happen much later, after the calls to `hookItUp` have long-since returned, the functions created when we called `hookItUp` still have access to the arguments we passed to it — when we click `element1`, we get "This message is for element1", and when we click `element2`, we get "And this one is for element2."

These are called closures. You can read more about them on my blog: *[Closures are not complicated](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)*

Comment: Cool, but this feels like you are recreating jQuery from scratch

Comment: @mplungjan: Event handlers are pretty much the easiest asynchronous callback for beginners to understand, and as the OP isn't using jQuery, I had to use the DOM...

Answer (score 2):

That'll work, but only if the declaration appears **after** the point in the DOM where the element actually appears. Try moving your `<script>` to the very end of the `<body>`.

Another thing you can do is use the window "load" event to make sure the whole DOM has been seen before your code runs.

Comment: Okay, so I put it after the point it appears, but can you tell me why we do this? Like I thought all scripts and such stay in the <head> or right at the beginning of the the <body>?

Comment: @LoganCerson: No, in fact the standard advice is to put scripts at the very **end** of the `body`, just before the closing `</body>` tag, unless you have a specific need to put them higher up. This is so that the scripts don't make your page seem to load more slowly than it needs to, and so that all of the elements your scripts might need to work with will exist. More: [YUI Best Practices for Speeding Up your Website](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom)

Comment: Thank you so much, this has helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

for example

```
var myGlobalVars = {"inferno":null,"othervar":null}; // globals in their own scope

function clickMe(varName,color) { // generic function
    myGlobalVars[varName].style.backgroundColor=color;
}

window.onload=function() {
  // initialise after the objects are available
  for (var o in myGlobalVars) myGlobalVars[o]=document.getElementById(o);
  // execute
  clickMe("inferno","red");
}
```

.
.

Answer (score 0):

T.J. Crowder gave a beautiful answer about scoping; just to add on that you can also use an immediately-invoked function expression to create a module with your UI elements, i.e.

```
var UI = (function() {
  ...
  return {
    inferno: document.getElementById("inferno");
  };
})();

...

UI.inferno.style = ...;
```